# ¿Como hallar el número mayor y menor en java con el for?

Tags: java

```
public class Actividad3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ent = new Scanner(System.in);

        int contamina = 0, auto= 25;
        int[] valores = new int [auto];
        double total = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= auto; i++) {
            System.out.println("Digite cantidad de contaminacion del auto " + i + ":");
            contamina = ent.nextInt();


        int max = valores [0];
        int min = valores[0];
        for(int a = 1; a <= auto; a++){
        if (valores[a]< min) {
            min = valores[a];
             }
        else if(valores[a] > max){
            max = valores[a];
        }

        }
        System.out.println("El carro que mas contamino es :" + max);
        System.out.println("El Carro que menos contamino es :" + min);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Y que se supone que deberia hacer eso?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Por favor **[edit] tu pregunta** explicando qué problemas tienes con este código y cuál es su propósito.

Comment: Aclara tu pregunta para poder darte respuestas mas acertadas. Tengo una respuesta fácil para tu problema, es usando Streams de JavaSE 8

Answer (score 1):

Tu inicializas el mínimo y el máximo como 0. Con el máximo eso no es ningún problema, pero con el mínimo si, asumiendo que todos los autos tienen valores de contaminación > 0.

```
public class Actividad3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ent = new Scanner(System.in);

        int contamina = 0, auto= 25;
        int[] valores = new int [auto];
        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= auto; i++) {
            System.out.println("Digite cantidad de contaminacion del auto " + i + ":");
            contamina = ent.nextInt();
            // supongo que quieres guardar los valores de contaminación aquí
            valores[i] = contamina;
        } // ingresemos todos los datos primero
        // int max = valores[0]; <- eso no tiene sentido, nunca inicializaste valores[0]
        // int min = valores[0]; <- idem

        // en una muestra de datos de tamaño 1, el dato es mínimo y máximo
        min = valores[1];
        max = valores[1];
        // luego solamente tenemos que iterar sobre el resto de los datos
        for(int a = 2; a <= auto; a++){
            if (valores[a]< min) {
                min = a;
            } else if(valores[a] > max){
                max = a;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("El carro que mas contamina (%d) es :  %d",
            valores[max],max));
        System.out.println(String.format("El carro que menos contamina (%d) es :  %d",
            valores[min],min));
    }
}
```